# React How to drag and drop element to a zone, and draggable element in a zone

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

I have a menu item, I select an item from that menu and drop down an area, then I can drag and move that element within that area. So now im using react-rnd, it warped react-draggable, but i dont know to drag an item that when the drop down it still has an item on the menu, and when dropping it is not on the way between the two regions.

I want to do like video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKthnJT2jNc

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-rnd-jyxyj?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Rnd } from "react-rnd";

const style = {
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  border: "solid 1px #ddd",
  background: "#f0f0f0",
  position: "absolute"
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ height: 150, borderWidth: 1, borderStyle: "solid" }}>
        <Rnd
          style={style}
          handle="handle"
          // bounds="body"
          // bounds="parent"
          default={{
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 100,
            height: 50
          }}
          draggableProps={{ allowAnyClick: true }}
        >
          Rnd
        </Rnd>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          height: 300,
          // width: 600,
          // position: "relative",
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderStyle: "solid"
        }}
      >
        <Rnd
          style={style}
          handle="handle"
          // bounds="body"
          bounds="parent"
          default={{
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 200,
            height: 150
          }}
          draggableProps={{ allowAnyClick: true }}
        >
          Rnd
        </Rnd>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks!